# Using Lambert W function - number of solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, lambert-w

I am solving this equation:

$$x^2e^{0.4x}=2$$

I managed to get here:

\begin{align*}
0.2xe^{0.2x} &= \pm0.2\sqrt{2}\\
0.2x &= W\bigl(\pm0.2\sqrt{2}\,\bigr)
\end{align*}

This, however, only results in $2$ solutions, while the graph on Geogebra/Desmos clearly yields three roots. Which part of the solution am I missing? I see no reason as to where a third root would disappear during my algebraic manipulation. Thank you for your help.

Comment: $W$ has two branches, so you have potentially four solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have correctly arrived at $$0.2x = W\bigl(\pm0.2\sqrt{2}\bigr),$$ which means that $$x = 5W\bigl(\pm0.2\sqrt{2}\bigr).$$ Now, $W$ has two branches, which for real numbers are $W_{0}$ and $W_{-1}$.  Now, $W_{0}(x)$ is defined for $x\ge -1/e$ and $W_{-1}(x)$ is defined for $x$ in $[-1/e,0).$  Now, since $-0.2\sqrt{2} \approx -0.283 > -1/e$ we will have three solutions:
\begin{align*}
5W_{0}\bigl(-0.2\sqrt{2}\,\bigr) &\approx-2.1926\\[5pt]
5W_{0}\bigl(0.2\sqrt{2}\,\bigr) &\approx 1.1285\\[5pt]
5W_{-1} \bigl(-0.2\sqrt{2}\,\bigr) &\approx -9.5497.
\end{align*}